# Create dynamically insert into table in Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, db2

i am trying to read from some db2 schema all the tables and for those tables to get their columns so i can create dynamically insert into statement
My data is stored in a list in this format:

```
list =
    [
      {'tableName1': ['col1','col2','col3',...]},
      {'tableName2': ['col1','col2','col3','col4',...]},
      ...
    ]
```

where tableName is the name of the table in my schema. So far i read from db catalog all tables and their columns and insert them into a list, but i don't know how to continue with iteration and create insert statement. SQL statement will be:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
```

In my case column1,column2,... are in the list and table name is also in the list. Table names are stored in the list, but table where we insert will have different prefix

Comment: As this is probably homework for class exercise, you need to try to work it out by yourself. You will not learn if someone else does your work.   One clue is that you need to know the column datatype for each column before you can get the correct insert statement, because to insert a character value from a variable is different to inserting a datetime, or timestamp, or a decimal number.

Comment: Why do i need to concern  with the data type? I will insert columns from source table to target table that has the same columns and data types but target table will have different prefix , for example DEV_TABLE1 is source table and target table is PRD_TABLE2 with the same columns

Comment: You only need to know the datatypes if you need a literal-value in the insert statement. When you are not using literal values or variables, you don't need to know the column datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have divided this problem in smaller parts and then try to form query string. Here I have done it for two tables. You can iterate for other tables according to your needs.

```
list1 =[
    {'tableName1': ['col1','col2','col3']},
    {'tableName2': ['col1','col2','col3','col4']}
]

dict1 = list1[0]
dict2 = list1[1]

table_name_1 = list(dict1.keys())[0]
table_name_2 = list(dict2.keys())[0]

table1_columns = tuple(dict1[table_name_1])
table2_columns = tuple(dict2[table_name_2])

query_string = f"INSERT INTO {table_name_2} ({', '.join(table2_columns)}) " \
               f"SELECT {', '.join(table1_columns)} FROM {table_name_1};"

print(query_string)
```

Comment: Tnx for the quick answer. I modified your code a little bit and add a for loop to go through list of my tables. There is one problem with a query_string variable, formatting is not good, there are no () when you use  join

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah, I missed the braces to add in query_string. But, string formatting is always good. It allows a developer to make the variables directly available in the string. Editing answer for the purpose of understanding.